# FasterCSV (seemingly) not working in Rails 3.0.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, fastercsv

I am trying to export data from a rails app and have the user download a CSV file when they hit a certain controller#action.

I found this article and used the sample code exactly.
http://oldwiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/HowtoExportDataAsCSV

I do, in fact, get a CSV file, but within it, there is only one line of output:

```
#<Proc:0x00000001032c6808@/PATH_CRAP/app/controllers/reports_controller.rb:35>
```

Here are lines 35, 36 and 37 from the file in question.

```
  render :text => Proc.new { |response, output|
    csv = FasterCSV.new(output, :row_sep => "\r\n") 
    yield csv
```

I am using Rails 3.0.5 and added the following to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'fastercsv'
```

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`render :text => proc {...}` does not work in Rails 3. For the replacement, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507594/ruby-on-rails-3-streaming-data-through-rails-to-client).

Comment: Thanks! I haven't been able to test this. I will tonight and will respond or, at least, check the green-check mark.