# export data to a sqlite3 database file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I'm trying to build a news article archival rails app.

The main goal is to allow all articles to be exported and download as a sqlite3 database file.

The purpose of that is so that the end user can use another app to view their articles offline.

I don't want to have to make an entire offline viewer if i can simply export data to the appropriate format.

tl:dr how to allow user to "download as sqlite3 database"?

Answer (score 0):

1. make the data as a CSV format file/object
2. create a blank sqlite3 db file.
3. import that CSV file/object into the SQLITE3 file
4. write a streaming action into the controller to send user the CSV file. refer to : [Ruby on Rails 3: Streaming data through Rails to client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507594/ruby-on-rails-3-streaming-data-through-rails-to-client)

Comment: >i have experience with 1 so that should be no problem
>2 seems simple enough if i'm understanding you correctly (basically FIle.new with a .db extension)
>3 is where you lost me, do you mean i should literally write csv data to that file? how do you do that?
>i'll check 4 out now

Comment: see here for importing CSV: http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ImportingFiles, also you need to google around.

Comment: i'll look at that, but it doesn't seem like it's going to solve my problem