# Continuously render rails template

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller action like this:

```
  def get_build_output
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @build_num = params[:build_num]

    has_more = true
    while has_more == true
      response = jenkins_client.job.get_console_output(@project.name, @build_num, 0, "html")
      @output = response["output"]
      has_more = response["more"]
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

And I have a `get_build_output.js.erb` file with:

```
$("#build_output").append("<%= raw escape_javascript(@output) %>");
```

What I'm trying to is continuously get output from a remote call and render it into the view, until has_more is false. Currently, the setup above only renders once and no more.

How can I re-render the page multiple times from the controller? And is there a better way to do what I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to render the page more than once. Just accumulate all the output in `@output` until there is none left, then render the page. The code you posted will almost do that -- but first, you need to move the `respond_to` call outside of the loop, and second, rather than `@output =`, you need `@output <<`. Also, you need to initialize `@output` to an empty string before the loop.

If you want to stream the output to the client as it is available, you can also do that. But that's a different question. If that's what you really want, see this: [Ruby on Rails 3: Streaming data through Rails to client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507594/ruby-on-rails-3-streaming-data-through-rails-to-client)

If you want to stream the output to the client, and you need to use your template to generate the output for each iteration of the loop, you can render a template to string with `render_to_string`. Here is the documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Rendering.html#method-i-render_to_string

Comment: But I want to render the output live as it comes in.